# Entity Framework does not save all changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im very close to tears on this one.

I have a user-object
this object has several properties FirstName, LastName etc. all simple types. String int etc.

These get loaded and updated fine.

```
public class Jobwalker
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }
    public TelephoneCountryCode TelephoneCountryCodeObject { get; set; }
    ...
```

But the userobject also has a property 'TelephoneCountryCodeObject' which is another class

```
public class TelephoneCountryCode
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public TelephoneCountryCode()
    {
    }
    ...
```

I can create delete an dmodify 'TelephoneCountryCode'-objects just fine,
but when i try to save an instance of a user-object only the simple types gets updated?

```
public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {

                db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Attach(TelephoneCountryCodeObject);
                Jobwalker result = (from jw in db.Jobwalkers
                                        .Include("TelephoneCountryCodeObject")
                                    where jw.UmbracoMemberID == UmbracoMemberID
                                    select jw).FirstOrDefault();


                db.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(this);

                if (this.TelephoneCountryCodeObject != null)
                {
                    result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Find(this.TelephoneCountryCodeObject.ID);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = null;
                }

                db.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I created this super simple test method

```
 public static void TEST()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {
                Jobwalker result = (from jw in db.Jobwalkers
                                        .Include("TelephoneCountryCodeObject")
                                    where jw.UmbracoMemberID == 1184
                                    select jw).FirstOrDefault();



                result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = TelephoneCountryCode.GetByName("denmark");
                db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Attach(result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject);
                result.FirstName = "Flemming";

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This works like it is supposed to. Then why the **** wont my regular Save() method work?

Comment: As a side note, the `using` statement implicitly uses a `try` block to protect against exceptions, so you do not need to wrap it in a silent try catch.

Comment: Jobwalker result = (from jw in db.Jobwalkers
                                        .Include("TelephoneCountryCodeObject")
                                    where jw.UmbracoMemberID == UmbracoMemberID
                                    select jw).FirstOrDefault();

are you sure that you get the right data returned ?

Comment: @Goran Štuc
Yes i get the correct user. When i try to set both the FirstName and TelephoneCountryCodeObject, FirstName gets updated but TelephoneCountryCodeObject remains null...

Comment: Maybe the TelephoneCountryCodeObject navigation property is not mapped correctly? Maybe it is mapped on the Jobwalker class but not on the User class? How it is mapped?

Comment: I think you should explain your question a little bit more. Are you using CodeFirst? Where is your `Save` method located? and how do you check that the `TelephoneCountryCode` is updated or not? (Do you run a sql query on SqlServer or just use your code)

Comment: @DavideIcardi
Sorry for the confusion my Jobwalker class IS my User class. I have updated the above code so the class names are correct

Comment: @Ashkan
Yes i am using codefirst. 
My Save method is located in my Jobwalker class.

This is the code i use to update:
    Jobwalker jw = Jobwalker.GetByUmbracoID(1184);
    jw.FirstName = "Flemminge";
    TelephoneCountryCode code = TelephoneCountryCode.GetByName("sweden");
    jw.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = code;
    jw.Save();

And i check the results in SQL Management Studio


Sidenote: How do i paste my code properly in a comment?

Comment: @FlyingHippo: ebmbrace your code in "\`", like this: \`Code...\`. About your code, I think the problem is that you are not using `Attach` method correctly. You should either attach your "dependent entity" to the db context or just set the "principal entity"'s related property. What you are doing here is a little confusing. For example why do you have this code: `if (this.TelephoneCountryCodeObject != null)
                {
                    result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Find(this.TelephoneCountryCodeObject.ID);
                }`

Comment: @Ashkan
I will admit that im fairly new to Entity Framework and some of the concepts confuses me.

I have simplified my 'Save' to this:
`using (var db = new MainContext())
{
db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Attach(TelephoneCountryCodeObject);  Jobwalker result = (from jw in db.Jobwalkers.Include("TelephoneCountryCodeObject") where jw.UmbracoMemberID == UmbracoMemberID select jw).FirstOrDefault();  db.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(this);  result.TelephoneCountryCodeObject = this.TelephoneCountryCodeObject;  db.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified; db.SaveChanges();}`
But i still doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to update an entity which is detached (for example you instantiated the object without fetching from database), you should have it's primary key and use the code below:

```
public void Update(Jobwalker detachedEntity)
{
    DB.Jobwalkers.Attach(detachedEntity);
    DB.Entry(detachedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

// in your code to save Jobwalker detached object do this:
Update(this); // `this` is the Jobwalker detached object
DB.SaveChanges();
```

There is no need for extra code, EF will detect your changes and update the entity and add the child entities to database.

Comment: same result :(.
only FirstName gets updated. Im beginning to think my code is just FUBAR

Comment: I dont understand why EF is so hard for me to use?

Im seriously considering getting rid of EF and converting everything to stored procedures instead. That way i know that if i tell the database to save something, it gets saved.

Comment: @FlyingHippo: As a piece of advice: Please be clear when you ask questions, mention exactly what you are trying to do! Once you know how to use EF, it becomes a piece of cake. You just need to clarify that either you want to add object to `DB.TelephoneCountryCodes` or just update the child entity (meaning the `jw.TelephoneCountryCodeObject`), I will tell you what to do!
Currently the code above adds the entity. I think you are trying to **Update** both `JobWalker` and it's child object of type `TelephoneCountryCode` !?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but i have come to the conclusion that my code is just too messed up.

Im gonna scratch everything and just start over.

I'll mark you answer as accepted, because it did help me a little.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to read stackoverflow questions about EF.

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely a result of `TelephoneCountryCodeObject` not being a dynamic proxy from the database, and probably just being a plain object. I believe that if you attach the result, then you will be able to save the changes.

```
Jobwalker result = (from jw in db.Jobwalkers
  .Include("TelephoneCountryCodeObject")
  where jw.UmbracoMemberID == UmbracoMemberID
  select jw).FirstOrDefault();
db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Attach(result);
```

Comment: db.TelephoneCountryCodes.Attach(result); wont work because result is of the type JobWalker, not TelephoneCountryCode