# Updating entity, all changes not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, razor

I have searched for this topic, and I realize there is a slightly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838761/entity-framework-does-not-save-all-changes), and while the problem sounds very similar, the accepted solution did not work (which, if one reads the comments, one will know that the problem wasn't really solved).

Here is my problem, and I hope someone can help:

I have an Entity:

```
public class Garden
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PlantHardinessZone Zone { get; set; }
}
```

It has a relationship with PlantHardinessZone Entity:

```
public class PlantHardinessZone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; }
}
```

In order to easily use the Zones in a DropDownListFor, I created a ViewModel:

```
public class GardenViewModel
{
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PlantHardinessZone> Zones { get; set; }

    public Garden Garden { get; set; }
}
```

This ViewModel is used in several views. It currently works as expected for Creating a new Garden entity, however, Editing is not functioning correctly. If I change the Zone, it is not updated in the DB. I have stepped through the code, and the correct Zone information is returning from the View, it is just not updating. If I change the name of the Garden, that updates fine.

Here is the [HttpPost} Edit Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(GardenViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Garden garden = viewModel.Garden;
            garden.Zone = db.Zones.Where(z => z.Id == viewModel.ZoneId).Single();
            db.Gardens.Attach(garden); // per the solution accepted [here][2]
            db.Entry(garden).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And here is the corresponding View:

```
@model GardenManager.Web.ViewModels.GardenViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Garden</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Garden.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Garden.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Garden.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Garden.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ZoneId,
                new SelectList(Model.Zones, "Id", "Zone", Model.ZoneId),
                "Select Zone", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Can anyone help direct me to solving this very annoying issue? All input welcome and appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: `db.Entry(garden).State = EntityState.Modified` only marks `garden` as modified, not its navigation properties. That's what causes your confusion. Using EF in a disconnected environment is not as easy as it should be. You have to traverse the whole object graph to get all modifications into the change tracker. There is a library, [Graphdiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) that can do this task for you.

Comment: My confusion comes because in my head, the Zone was being changed, just the FK in Garden pointing to the proper Zone. As per the answer, I have added an explicit FK (ZoneId), and updating that worked as I would have expected. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the state of **Garden** to `Modified` but that does not have any effect on the navigation properties (the link to **Zone**). Thus EF will update only **Garden**, with no effect on the linked **Zone**.

If, however, you assign the **Zone** by it's `ID`, to `garden.ZoneId`, that will work. `garden.ZoneId` is a direct property of **Garden** and it will get everything properly linked.

```
garden.ZoneId = db.Zones.Where(z => z.Id == viewModel.ZoneId).Single().Id;
```

To recapitulate:
 - `garden.Zone` **is not a true property** of the object, it's just a link handled behind the scenes by EF. This is why it fails updating.
- `garden.ZoneId` **is a true property** of the object, thus it get's updated properly if you change it.

`db.Gardens.Attach(garden);` attaches only the `garden` object. It doesn't attach the other objects that might be linked to it.

Additionally I would recommend to first attach the entity to the context and then change it's properties and state.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, **Zone** isn't actually changing, just the FK that identifies which **Zone**, but that is still saved within **Garden**, unless I am missing something.
I did try `db.Entry(garden.Zone).State = EntityState.Added;`

I also tried `db.Entry(garden.Zone).State = EntityState.Modified;`, but that presented an error at run: `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.` I have tried to correct that to, however, no luck.

Comment: I have, yes. I had to add an explicit property for **ZoneId** and migrate, which I did. It worked, so thank you very much. I am not sure why that made such a difference, but I am still learning. :) Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. That makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the time you took to further explain. When I get enough rep, I will upvote. :)